# How can validate 3 dates in row from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

how i can validate that i have been picked 3 dates in row.

Example:

[image]

Lets say if i had 3 dates in row i want to alert some message.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you show what you tried so we can work on that, please add a code snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Where is your code? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yuo can get the code here:
http://likethislikethat.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly what you need.

First of all, you have to `split` values and `wrap` them in an `array`.Then, you must to check if values are for consecutive `days`.

```
function diffDays(date1,date2){
   return parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));  
}
$('button').click(function(){
    var values=$('input').val().split(',').map(function(item){
        return new Date(item);
    });
    var result=checkValues(values);
    if(result==1){
       alert('Yes');
    }
    else{
       alert('No');
    }
});
function checkValues(values){
    values.sort(function(a,b){return a.getTime() - b.getTime()});
    if(values.length<3){
       return 0;
    }
    else{
       var exist=0;
       console.log(values);
       for(i=0;i<values.length-2;i++){
            if(diffDays(values[i],values[i+1])==1 && diffDays(values[i+1],values[i+2])==1){
                exist=1;
            }
       }
       return exist;
    }  
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/LcqM7/706/)

Comment: Thanks but what about if I want to select more than 3 days.
And just want to check if somewhere in this days we have 3 in a row

Comment: @lisi4ok, in few moments i will try to update my code.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code as per your need: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/LcqM7/707/](http://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/LcqM7/707/)

This check dates in same row but not mandatory in same sequence.

```
<div id="divDates">
    <input id="txtDates" type="text" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <button id="btnValidate">
    Validate
    </button>
</div>


$('#divDates input').datepicker({
    multidate: true
});
$('#btnValidate').click(function(){
     var values=$('#txtDates').val().split(',');       
     checkDatesInRow(values);       
});

function checkDatesInRow(Dates){
  var curr = new Date(Dates[0]); // get current date
  var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
  var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

  var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
  var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last));

  var IsValid=true;
  for(var i=0;i<Dates.length;i++){
     var dateSelected = new Date(Dates[i]);
     if(dateSelected>=firstday && dateSelected<=lastday){

     }
     else{
       IsValid=false;
     }
  }

  if(IsValid){
     alert("In same row");
  }
  else{
    alert("Not in same row");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what about if I want to select more than 3 days.
And just want to check if somewhere in this days we have 3 in a row

Comment: I have updated answer and fiddle code. This check dates in same row but not mandatory in same sequence as in above answer it require to select dates in sequence